# Loading content only when needed with an iframe - potential pitfalls and alternatives?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

*I'm sorry if this question is not very appropriate.*

I have a website. When a user enters it for the first time, I want to show a box with an embedded YouTube video, some social media share buttons, etc. On subsequent page loads, this box will only be opened by the user through a button. It's pretty straightforward, I can have a `<div>` that is hidden based on a `localStorage` flag and `onclick` event.

However, when the user enters the page for the second time, all that data (YouTube video, social buttons) would be loaded and then immediately hidden. If the user decides to not click the button that shows the data, it would have been loaded for no apparent reason. That's bad because it crushes page load times for nothing.

### What I've done:

I put all the content (YouTube video, etc) in a separate HTML page. In my main page, I have an `<iframe>` with `src=""`. When I want to show the content, I simply do `src="content.html"`. This way, the data is only loaded when it's needed.

### Questions:

What are the possible problems I could experience with my solution? Is it considered bad practice? Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

A problem I see is with using `localStorage` to set the status. You should consider using a `cookie`.

Cookies allow you to set an expiration date. So a one-time visitor doesn't retain data forever.

Also be aware that both methods can be deactivated in the browser, so you should check if you can even set the value.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies
and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/cookieEnabled

The no-no with `iframe`s is to "adorn oneself with borrowed plumes", i.e. inserting external pages into your own, making it look like your content.